# Form implemented using form_alter not always showing the changed contents in select list

Tags: views, forms, hooks

I have created a module to alter a  select dropdown of a view's exposed filter like this

```
function myform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 

   if ($form_id == "views_exposed_form" && $form['#id'] == "views-exposed-form-staff-page") {
$form['field_department_tid']['#type'] = "select";
    $form['field_department_tid']['#size'] = null;
    $form['field_department_tid']['#default_value'] = $form['field_department_tid']['#options']['All'];
    $form['field_department_tid']['#options'] = array(
      'All' => t('All Offices'),
      '6' => t("Office of the Chairman"),

'Administration & Financial Affairs Department' => array(
            '2'=> t('Administration'),
            '3' => t('Finance'),
            '4' => t('HR'),

         ),



    );
 }
```

But occasionally it is showing the original unaltered select list instead of the new select list and in such cases, I need to clear cache every time to display the changed dropdown.

What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

Change

`$form['field_department_tid']['#default_value'] = $form['field_department_tid']['#options']['All'];`

to

`$form['field_department_tid']['#default_value'] =  t('All Offices');`

Comment: It is not a sing value that is not showing, but entire set